# Android FragmentVIewPager and screen re-draw issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

We're having a spot of a problem with the FragmentViewPager and Fragments.

We are using the CursorLoader to populate a list within a Fragment. The view pager consists of 4 pages.

Basically when swiping from one fragment to another it works just fine, but once we pull data from a service in the context of say fragment A and swipe to fragment B then C and so on, the list within the Fragment appears to not load i.e. a blank screen, but if the screen of the device is turned off and then on the list within the Fragment displays the data.

In the onLoadFinished method of the cursor loader we reset the adapter on every refresh.

I'm stumped for a solution. Any advice?

Additional Info, I also sometimes receive this stack trace.

> 09-21 15:20:44.489: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):
>   Landroid/view/ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException;: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   09-21 15:20:44.497: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932) 09-21
>   15:20:44.497: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:629) 09-21
>   15:20:44.501: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.501:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.501:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.501:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:257)
>   09-21 15:20:44.517: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:4641) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:3116) 09-21 15:20:44.517:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:713)
>   09-21 15:20:44.517: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:697) 09-21
>   15:20:44.517: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:812)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(CursorAdapter.java:391)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.deactivateInternal(AbstractCursor.java:89)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.close(AbstractCursor.java:108) 09-21
>   15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:504)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:594)
>   09-21 15:20:44.525: INFO/dalvikvm(21106):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Thanks,

Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seemed to have figured out the reason why this occurs, but don't really have an explanation, maybe someone could elaborate on this.

The response from the server used a service+ResultReceiver in the fragment to notify the UI of the background httpservice completion which works fine when used in an activity, but with a fragment any hook into the UI from the handler resulted in the UI crashing, as if a UI change was made from a separate thread, with no consistent complaint in the logs, other than the occasional error as seen above. Once we used a handler in the result receiver to notify the UI of a change we don't face this problem any longer.

Akshay